# Oracle InstantClient ODBC connection fails in DbProviderFactory when the ODBC Test Connect succeeds

Tags: c#, .net, oracle11g, instantclient, dbproviderfactories

- Installed the InstantCLient 11.2.0.4 Basic Lite and ODBC packages
- Set up the ORACLE_HOME and TNS_ADMIN environment variables and added the path for the installation to the Path environment variable
- Created my tnsnames.ora file in that location
- Set up my DSN using the TNS in the file and did a test connection - succeeded.
- Used C# code I had developed before which uses the DbProviderFactoies generic method of connecting to Data Providers (already works with Teradata, SQL Server)
- Created my Data Source configuration with the following connectionString:
  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DataSource" connectionString="DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_11_2};Data Source=Test Oracle;Persist Security Info=True;Password=password;User=user" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  </configuration>`
- Results in "ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error".
- I tried many variants on the connection string and they all lead to an error of some sort. Any help will be much appreciated.

*System Information*

- Windows Server 2003 64 Bit
- C# .NET 3.5
- Oracle 11g 11.2.0.3.0 remote database

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what was wrong, but I discovered that the very simple connection string below worked! It is using the generic System.Data.Odbc too.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataSource" connectionString="DSN=MyDSN;Uid=user;Pwd=password" providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which protocol you are using to connect: **`TCP`** or **`TCPS`**.
If **`TCPS`**, then the `.NET Framework` version should be above **4.5.**
You get "`ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`" if the `.NET Framework` version is below **3.5.**